# WebSocket is not working when app is in background or device is locked

Tags: ios, swift, websocket

I am new to Swift. I am implementing a WebSocket client for iOS application. I am using **SwiftWebSocket** client library for the same. My WebSocket gets connected to the WebSocket Server successfully.

WebSocket server is sending messages to its clients and clients, on receiving messages, will process them. When my app is in foreground, everything is working fine. But, the problem is when my app is in background, WebSocket client is not receiving messages from the server even though it is connected to it. Also if I lock my iPhone device, WebSocket client gets disconnected.

My app's requirement is - even if my app is in background and/or device is locked, my WebSocket client should remain connected with Server and it should receive and process all messages from server.

Can I have something in background which will keep my WebSocket client connected to server and allow it to receive and process all messages.

Is it possible to achieve? What should be my approach?

Comment: you might need to check Background modes.

Comment: You should take a look at Apples documentation about BackgroundExecution https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html